# Время жизни в Rust

Tags: графы, rust

Только недавно начал изучать rust и ради интереса решил реализовать генерацию простого графа на нем. Собственно сам код:

```
pub struct Edge {
    edges: Vec<Edge>
}

impl Edge {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Edge {
            edges: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, edge: Edge) {
        self.edges.push(edge);
    }
}

pub struct EdgeFactory {
    n: i32,
    rand: Vec<i32>
}

impl EdgeFactory {
    pub fn create() -> Self {
        EdgeFactory {
            n: 3,
            rand: vec!(2 , 1, 2)
        }
    }

    pub fn n(&mut self, new: i32) -> &Self {
        self.n = new;

        self
    }

    fn rand(&mut self) -> i32 {
        match self.rand.pop() {
            Some(num) => num,
            None => 0
        }
    }

    pub fn build(&mut self) -> Edge {
        let edge = Edge::new();
        let mut queue: Vec<&mut Edge> = Vec::new();

        while queue.len() != 0 {
            let val = queue.pop().unwrap();

            for _ in 0 .. self.rand() {
                let mut nedge = Edge::new();
                queue.push(&mut nedge);
                val.push(nedge);
            }
        }

        edge
    }
}
```

Который выдает ошибку "`nedge` does not live long enough" в методе build. Причина ошибки мне понятна - ссылка на nedge "Живет" меньше, чем вектор queue. Но не очень понятно как решать такие проблемные ситуации

Comment: Судя по определению структуры `Edge`, то что вы пытаетесь сделать больше похоже на дерево, чем на граф. Логика работы `EdgeFactory` мне вообще непонятна.

Советую посмотреть как устроен граф в известной библиотеке [petgraph](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html). 

Про проблемы с временами жизни при построении структур данных есть хорошая книжка [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/). Но это далеко не начальный уровень.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сам код - просто пример проблемы. Не более. Гораздо интереснее научиться решать такие проблемы в Rust. Попробую разобраться в этом вопросе на примерах из книжки

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `queue` типа `Vec<Edge>`.

`nedge` действительно недостаточно долго живёт, потому что лежит в лескическом блоке, который вложен в блок, в котором лежит `queue`. Компилятор Rust прикидывает, что как только исполнение покинет блок, где был создан `nedge`, тот будет удалён со стека. А вы пытаетесь сохранить ссылку, живущую дольше, чем сам объект `nedge` (что, если бы программа скомпилировалась, привело бы к чтению "мусора").

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот в этом месте:

```rust
queue.push(&mut nedge);
val.push(nedge);
```

Вы хотите сохранить ссылку на объект `nedge`, который затем перемещается в другое место, и это перемещение инвалидирует ссылку. Так делать нельзя.

В общем случае в Rust вам нужно спланировать, кто будет **владеть** объектом, а кто будет его **временно заимствовать** у владельца. При этом важно, во-первых, чтобы владелец жил дольше, чем тот, кто у него заимствует данные, а во-вторых, вы можете иметь только одно заимствование, если оно мутабельное.

Если вы не можете выделить единственного владельца, а с объектом нужно работать из многих мест, то целесообразно в таком случае разместить объект в куче за "умным указателем" `Rc` или `Arc`. Счетчик ссылок будет гарантировать освобождение памяти тогда, когда объект станет никому не нужен:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
        
pub struct Edge {
    edges: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Edge>>>
}

impl Edge {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Edge {
            edges: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, edge: Rc<RefCell<Edge>>) {
        self.edges.push(edge);
    }
}

pub struct EdgeFactory {
    n: i32,
    rand: Vec<i32>
}

impl EdgeFactory {
    pub fn create() -> Self {
        EdgeFactory {
            n: 3,
            rand: vec!(2 , 1, 2)
        }
    }

    pub fn n(&mut self, new: i32) -> &Self {
        self.n = new;

        self
    }

    fn rand(&mut self) -> i32 {
        match self.rand.pop() {
            Some(num) => num,
            None => 0
        }
    }

    pub fn build(&mut self) -> Edge {
        let edge = Edge::new();
        let mut queue: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Edge>>> = Vec::new();

        while queue.len() != 0 {
            let val = queue.pop().unwrap();

            for _ in 0 .. self.rand() {
                let nedge = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Edge::new()));
                queue.push(nedge.clone());
                val.borrow_mut().push(nedge);
            }
        }

        edge
    }
}
```

`RefCell` здесь необходим потому, что мы должны заимствовать для изменения объект, который скрыт за `Rc`. В случае `Arc` вместо него будет, например, `Mutex`.

Другой вариант состоит в том, чтобы вместо ссылок использовать сырые указатели, но тогда вам придется добавлять блок `unsafe` и самим гарантировать безопасность того, что вы напишете:

```rust
pub fn build(&mut self) -> Edge {
    let edge = Edge::new();
    let mut queue: Vec<*mut Edge> = Vec::new();

    while queue.len() != 0 {
        let val = queue.pop().unwrap();

        for _ in 0 .. self.rand() {
            let nedge = Edge::new();
            unsafe {
                (*val).push(nedge);
                queue.push((*val).edges.last_mut().unwrap() as *mut _)
            }
        }
    }

    edge
}
```